# Local report RDLC to PDF

Tags: c#, performance

[image]Is there any way to improve the performance of local report or even an alternative if not? I have been looking for a solution for quite some time but the general consensus seems to be that it's just slow.

```
public byte[] genReportBytes(int id, string fromm,string too,string filetype)
{
    reportDetails repD = new reportDetails();
    repD = getOneReport(id);

    LocalReport report = new LocalReport();

    if (fromm != null)
        repD.ParametersCommandLine = "@startdate=" + fromm;

    if (too != null)
        repD.ParametersCommandLine += " @enddate=" + too;

    string RDLCPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RDLCPath"];
    string ReportOutputPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportOutputPath"];

    string RDLCName = repD.RDLCName;
    RDLCPath += @"\" + RDLCName;
    report.ReportPath = RDLCPath;

    string sqlGet = repD.SQLOfReport;

    report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(repD.DatasetName, getReportData(sqlGet, repD.ParametersCommandLine)));

    // export to byte array

    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streamids;
    string mimeType;
    string encoding;
    string filenameExtension;
    string deviceInf = "";
    byte[] bytes;
    string extension;

    if (filetype == "pdf")
    {
        deviceInf = "<DeviceInfo><PageHeight>8.5in</PageHeight><PageWidth>11in</PageWidth><MarginLeft>0in</MarginLeft><MarginRight>0in</MarginRight></DeviceInfo>";
        //fileName = ReportOutputPath + @"\" + repD.NameOfOutputPDF + ".PDF";
        bytes = report.Render("pdf", deviceInf, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
        out streamids, out warnings);
    }
    else
    {
        //fileName = ReportOutputPath + @"\" + repD.NameOfOutputPDF + ".XLS";
        bytes = report.Render(
              "Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding,
               out extension,
              out streamids, out warnings);
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code in the `LocalReport` class? Of particular interest is the `Render` method.

Comment: Local report is a Microsoft class referenced by   Microsoft.Reporting;

Comment: You may want to [edit] and include the SQL involved, and *maybe* the content of the .rdlc file - but I suspect the longest part is *running the report*, not *rendering* it; in which case what needs to be optimized is the source query, not the C# code that exports the rendered report.

Comment: @Joe127 My bad, can I assume that LocalReport's Render function is taking most of the performance? Have you tried any profiling?

Comment: Ya it seems to be the Render function alright, I inserted a break point at the render function and its gets there fairly instantly but then there is delay of up to ten seconds for larger reports, Thanks

Comment: Could you post the code for getReportData()? If it returns an IEnumerable, then it could be the bottleneck when enumerated in Render since some IEnumerables return instantly before the data is fetched (in this case it would block on the first entry being retrieved).

Answer (score 1):

Your naming conventions are hard to follow, or you're not following them; either way, you're not following the standard/recommended/established conventions.

```
public byte[] genReportBytes(int id, string fromm,string too,string filetype)
```

Public members should be `PascalCase`; locals and parameters should be `camelCase`. That would make the signature read like this:

```
public byte[] GenReportBytes(int id, string fromm, string too, string fileType)
```

`getOneReport(id)` would be `GetOneReport(id)`, and `getReportData(sqlGet, repD.ParametersCommandLine))` would be `GetReportData(sqlGet, repD.ParametersCommandLine))`, and `streamids` would be `streamIds`.

But if I had to pick only 1 name to change, it would be this one:

```
reportDetails repD = new reportDetails();
```

`reportDetails` is a **TYPE** and should be `PascalCase` like *every single other type name in the framework*. Notice how that one even gets the syntax highlighter confused?

---

The `filetype` parameter is *stringly typed*, and wants to be an `enum`. And I don't understand the doubling-up of `m` in `fromm` and `o` in `too` - if that's just to make `from` and `to` usable names, you have two options:

1. Prefix with a `@` verbatim specifier, making them `@from` and `@to`. Seriously though, don't do that.
2. Give them a meaningful name; I'd match them with the parameters they're mapped to, so that would be `startDate` and `endDate`.

---

<sub>There are other points to add, but I have to go... will come back and edit this answer if no one else points them out by then.</sub>

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but the OP asked about performance and you commented on naming conventions. Is that standard practice for CR.SE?

Comment: @agrothe reviewers are always free to comment on any & all aspects of the code. Feel free to add an answer if you see any way to improve anything, including performance. As I commented on the OP, a slow report could be caused by inefficient SQL source query, which OP never edited in.